# Can drawings be accessed in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can I "read" in a pine script script the drawings on a chart ?

Example: I manually draw a horizontal line (say it's a support level) and I want to have the info about that line in my script (the price where I think there is a support level).

Answer (score 0):

No, user drawn objects are not accesible.

You can have user inputs for that or need to somehow calculate the support and resistance levels programmatically.